# Http Post request via prolog

Tags: http, post, prolog, swi-prolog

I'm trying to do a post request via prolog to another rest api. Something along the lines of (if i were to do it in js):

```
body={

login="login",

passsword="password"

}

axios.post("http://localhost:5000",body);
```

I'm not trying to post TO prolog, i'm trying to post FROM prolog to another api.

I don't know how to add the body as json and set Content-Type to application/json.

This is what i've come up with so far:

```
% Bibliotecas
:- use_module(library(http/thread_httpd)).
:- use_module(library(http/http_dispatch)).
:- use_module(library(http/http_parameters)).
:- use_module(library(http/http_ssl_plugin)).
:- use_module(library(http/http_open)).
:- use_module(library(http/http_json)).

% Routes
:- http_handler('/auth', auth, []).
:- http_handler('/send_file_post', send_file_post, []).

% Cria��o de servidor HTTP no porto 'Port'
server(Port) :-
        http_server(http_dispatch, [port(Port)]).

auth(Request) :-
  http_read_json(Request, DictIn,[json_object(dict)]),
   format(user_output,"Request is: ~p~n",[Request]),
   format(user_output,"DictIn is: ~p~n",[DictIn]),
   DictOut=DictIn,
   reply_json(DictOut),

   http_client:http_post('http://localhost:5000/api/users/authenticate', DictOut,Reply, [content("application/json")]),
  http_read_data(Reply, Data, []).
```

To add further clarification:

I make a post request to my prolog http server, in its body i have an email and a password. my end goal is to make a second post request to another api with the same email/password.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `http_post/4`.

https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=http_post/4

```
http_post([ protocol(http),
            host(localhost),
            port(5000),
            path('/mypostpage')
          ],
          form_data([ login = myusername,
                      password = pass123
                    ]),
          Reply,
          []).
```

Would send a post request to `http://localhost:5000/mypostpage`